# %%time magic function Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to understand the difference when I stick `%%time` at the top of any given cell, the cell runs pretty fast and without `%%time`, it takes a much longer time. Any idea why the difference?

```
#%%time
start_time = time.time()
[some code]
.
.
print (time.time() - start_time)
```

takes 180s

On the other hand, when I run this:

```
%%time
start_time = time.time()
[some code]
.
.
print (time.time() - start_time)
```

it takes 20s

I do not know why there is such a huge difference?